# How to set a asterisk at taskbar look like skype preview app?

Tags: c++, uwp, win-universal-app

When i created a project universal app, I want make a asterisk in icon in taskbar to notification to user about some event. it look like skype preview app when received a new message(it will display a asterisk at taskbar).
Can you help me to how to set it(asterisk) in universal app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code (from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-badges)) should do it:

```
private void updateBadgeGlyph() {
    string badgeGlyphValue = "alert";

    // Get the blank badge XML payload for a badge glyph
    XmlDocument badgeXml = BadgeUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(BadgeTemplateType.BadgeGlyph);

    // Set the value of the badge in the XML to our glyph value
    Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement badgeElement = badgeXml.SelectSingleNode("/badge") as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement;
    badgeElement.SetAttribute("value", badgeGlyphValue);

    // Create the badge notification
    BadgeNotification badge = new BadgeNotification(badgeXml);

    // Create the badge updater for the application
    BadgeUpdater badgeUpdater = BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication();

    // And update the badge
    badgeUpdater.Update(badge);
}
```

Or you can use [NotificationsExtensions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2016/05/23/notificationsextensions-updated-for-anniversary-update-of-windows-10/) for it, which is also helpful for creating Tile layouts.